# YAML to JSON with Python, Kubernetes api call

Tags: python, json, docker, kubernetes, yaml

I want to convert this file into json format, does anyone know how to do it?

This is the yaml file :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: theiaide
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  #name: rewrite
  name: theiaide
  namespace: theiaide
  annotations:
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: ide.quantum.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: theiaide
          servicePort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: theiaide
 namespace: theiaide
spec:
 ports:
 - port: 80
   targetPort: 3000
 selector:
   app: theiaide
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: theiaide
  name: theiaide
  namespace: theiaide
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: theiaide
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: theiaide
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: theiaide/theia-python
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: theiaide
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
```

**code.py**

```
import json,yaml
txt=""
with open(r"C:\Users\77922\PycharmProjects\ide-ingress.yaml",'r') as f:
    for a in f.readlines():
        txt=txt+a
print(yaml.dump(yaml.load_all(txt),default_flow_style=False))
print(json.dumps(yaml.load_all(txt),indent=2,sort_keys=True))
```

when I run python code.py ,and I got the error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle generator objects
```

I don’t know if it is the reason for this --- delimiter, because there are multiple --- delimiters in my yaml file

Then I tried the following function:

```
def main():

    # config.load_kube_config()

    f = open(r"C:\Users\77922\PycharmProjects\ide-ingress.yaml","r")
    generate_dict  = yaml.load_all(f,Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    generate_json = json.dumps(generate_dict)
    print(generate_json)
    # dep = yaml.load_all(f)
    # k8s_apps_v1 = client.AppsV1Api()
    # resp = k8s_apps_v1.create_namespaced_deployment(
    #     body=dep, namespace="default")
    # print("Deployment created. status='%s'" % resp.metadata.name)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
 raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type generator is not JSON serializable
```

I just want to use this yaml file to call kubernetes api to generate namespace

Comment: Why do you need to dump it to JSON?  If you already have that YAML, using `subprocess.call(['kubectl', 'apply', '-f', 'ide-ingress.yaml'])` could load it, or as you show in the last example, the [Kubernetes Python client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) has native data structures and APIs for Kubernetes objects.

Comment: @Layne Wu is the solution posted by Ewerton solved your issue?

Comment: @DavidMaze In fact, I just want to use the API to call, but currently create deployment fails. The creation of igress namespace and service is successful.

Comment: @DawidKruk Yes, Ewerton helped me solve this file conversion problem, but I seem to be discussing something else with David Maze. Do I need to open a new question to discuss it?

Answer (score 3):

Your file contains more than one document. You should use the `safe_load_all` function rather than `yaml.load` and `list` rather than `json.dumps`

```
import json,yaml
txt=""
with open(r"C:\Users\77922\PycharmProjects\ide-ingress.yaml",'r') as f:
    for a in f.readlines():
        txt=txt+a
print(yaml.dump_all(yaml.safe_load_all(txt),default_flow_style=False))
print(list(yaml.safe_load_all(txt)))
```

Comment: I tried it and it seems that there were other errors. I updated it.